# Hydrogen under pressure and high temperatere released energy: what is this process?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, hydrogen

I am given hydrogen that is put into some pressure and high temperature conditions. After this it was found out that mass has decreased. It was also found that energy was released.
Can someone, please, explain why energy was actually released? And if I would be given initial and result  mass, how to find the amount energy that as released (if it is possible)?

Comment: PLease provide your source for this assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If hydrogen lost mass due to high pressure and high temperature it is probably fusion that is happening(unlikely to happen in large amounts on Earth) and often happens in stars. Energy was released because the two hydrogen nuclei or protons have a higher mass because they are less stable when apart than together when in the form of deuterium where one of the protons is converted to a neutron after the fusion reaction.

This is important to note that because the universe typically likes to drop to the lowest energy state possible so the higher temperature and pressure allows the particles to have the high velocities and this can either help quantum tunneling be more likely to fuse the nuclei together, or if the particle amount is low, actually can cause the nuclei to overcome the Coloumb barrier preventing fusion. These conditions make it possible for the particles to reach their goal of going to the lowest energy state, so it is more likely to happen.

So essentially this is why energy is released because it is possible for energy to be released under those conditions of high temperature and pressure.

To calculate the energy released, you just need to subtract off the final mass from the initial mass to find the amount of mass that is lost, and then convert it to kilograms and then multiply it by speed of light squared to get the energy in Joules.